# undefined method `content_type' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Strange error in diagnostics.erb file about `_set_controller_content_type`.

Please help.

```
NoMethodError in Timelines#public_timeline

Showing /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb where line # raised:

undefined method `content_type' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #):

RAILS_ROOT: /Volumes/DATA/Source/Rails/tvider

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:52:in `method_missing'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/base.rb:331:in `_set_controller_content_type'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:32:in `block in render'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in `render'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:134:in `rescue_action_locally'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:152:in `rescue_action_without_handler'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:74:in `rescue_action'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:162:in `rescue in perform_action_with_rescue'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_with_rescue'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:146:in `perform_action_with_flash'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_with_filters'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:437:in `call'
Request

Parameters:

None
Show session dump

Response

Headers:

{"Cache-Control"=>"no-cache",
 "Content-Type"=>""}
```

Comment: Show yor code, which return this error

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if this is the cause of your error.  But when I got this error, it was because I unthinkingly defined a "response" action in my controller.  Renamed the action, and all was well.

Code Example:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def request
  end

  def response
  end

end
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick! I also had a similar problem (defined a response action in my controller). Renamed that and now works like a charm. Thanks for posting this.

Comment: I had this error because I defined a 'request' action. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you defined a "response action" in your controller?

Comment: I had this same error also because I had define a 'request' action!

Comment: as @bcackerman said.. what do you mean define a response action?  Could you give a smidge of code?

Answer (score 2):

What **action** are you trying to call in the **controller** ?

check the action_name in the controller !